# Dots in Cura on Prepare-mode

Tags: ultimaker-cura

When I load a figure in Cura 4.6.1 I get weird dots all over my figure in `Prepare`-mode.

[image]

How come, and can I turn it off?

It's on every model I load :( I am fairly sure the normals are facing the correct way as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found!

If `Display model errors` is disabled, the dots appears.
Check the setting, hit `OK`, click on the box and they disappear.

[image]